# Conditionally inject dependencies during angularjs module initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular module which I want to have a dependency injected into it conditionally. i.e.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myappcontroller',
  'ngGrid'              // I want to include ngGrid only if I am running a debug version of myapp
]);
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Almost but not quite a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875714/angular-js-re-open-and-add-dependencies-to-an-already-bootstrapped-application

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can, but with a bit of extra work.

The second parameter is an array so nothing prevents you from doing this:

```
var dev = ['foo', 'bar'];
var prod = ['foo'];
var deps = dev; //or prod


angular.module('foo', []);
angular.module('bar', []);

angular.module('myApp', deps);
```