# Conditionally inject angular module dependency

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and have the following code.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'conditionalDependency',
        function ($scope, $http, conditionalDependency{
}
```

I would like to have **conditionalDependency** loaded conditionally. Something like this

```
if(true)
{
//add conditionalDependency
}
```

How can this be done. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851373/conditionally-inject-dependencies-during-angularjs-module-initialization)  . However, my requirement is that I have the dependency specified in **function**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this for performances/bandwidth reasons or for an application/structural point of view? Short answer: you cannot do that natively but there are some interesting articles about it on the internet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not quite clear as to why you would *have* to have it in a named function like in your example but...

If you need conditional dependencies, I would suggest taking a look at the following:

[Conditional injection of a service in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721530/conditional-injection-of-a-service-in-angularjs)

I've used this method in a couple niche scenarios and it works quite well.

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
angular.module('myApp').controller('loginController', 
    ['$injector', '$scope', '$http',
    function($injector, $scope, $http) {
        var service;

        if (something) {
            service = $injector.get('myService');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it even without injecting injector in your controller

```
if(something){
   var injector = angular.element(document).injector();
   var myService  = injector.get('myService')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

1. `angular.injector().get('conditionalDep');`
2. You can inject `$injector` once to your file and call `$injector.get('dep')`;