# Add Angular Module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I am trying to add angular-gantt plugins to my application. Firstly;

```
angular.module('myApp',['directives', 'services', 'controllers', ... and some more]
```

Then when I need angular-gantt on my application I want to add some extra modules to 'myApp' like;

```
angular.module('myApp',['gantt','gantt-sortable','gantt-movable',.. and some more]
```

But when I do that pages disapper and nothing works. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Check the console for errors. Do you include your library files in your HTML page ?

Comment: Show us the console log and the code itself

Comment: Are both those 2 lines running in your code? Or just the one?

Comment: The project is too big to share. When I try to add new modules, existing modules are lost. This is the problem. I want to add new modules to 'myApp' without losting existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different syntax when adding to existing module, otherwise the module gets recreated/overwritten. 
From https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module:

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the
>   module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use
>   angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

and the example that follows:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

// add some directives and services
myModule.service('myService', ...);
myModule.directive('myDirective', ...);

// overwrites both myService and myDirective by creating a new module
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

// throws an error because myOtherModule has yet to be defined
var myModule = angular.module('myOtherModule');
```

Edit: please also look here for much more detailed discussion: 
[re-open and add dependencies to an already bootstrapped application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875714/angular-js-re-open-and-add-dependencies-to-an-already-bootstrapped-application)