# angularjs add new dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add a new dependency, the 'angular-file-upload' dependency, but what ever I do, my app crashes, I can't understand how it works. What I've got now is:

in app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

in appController.js

```
myApp.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
```

I've got all necessary resource files (angular-file-upload.js) and references to them, I just don't know how to properly inject the new dependency. I'm thinking I only need to edit the two provided lines, or do I have to create a whole new controller, and if so, what should that look like?

It says that my question is a possible duplicate of another, but on the other question it's about injecting dependencies into config() modules, this is not the case here.

Comment: You didn't specify new dependency.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875714/angular-js-re-open-and-add-dependencies-to-an-already-bootstrapped-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean this project: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload
then the snytax is like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angularFileUpload']);

myApp.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function ($scope, FileUploader) {
}]);
```

Comment: It works, but I am sure I tried that, possibly I wrote 'angularFileUpload' in the controller, thank you, and everyone else who answered also.

Comment: @user3266024 No problem. But if you really want to thank people then the best way is to vote up on their answers

Answer (score 1):

You should write it like following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angular-file-upload']);
```

That's it. The dependence module should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The example below describes how to inject the stuff you would like to use. It is from [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

```
//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', function ($scope, Upload) {
                                    ^^^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^
    $scope.$watch('files', function () {
        $scope.upload($scope.files);
    });

    $scope.upload = function (files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'upload/url',
                    fields: {'username': $scope.username},
                    file: file
                }).progress(function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('error status: ' + status);
                })
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the file to your **angular.module**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angular-file-upload']);
```

And import the file (for example in your index.html):

```
<script src="yourpath/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="yourpath/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
```

If you correctly install your dependency, it should works :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the dependency to the Angular instance

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angularFileUpload']);
```

And add into your controller:

```
myApp.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
```

See the example on their Git page https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/examples/simple/controllers.js

Answer (score 1):

From the [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Introduction) wiki:

- Add the dependency in your module declaration, these will be **all** the angular modules your application needs.

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angularFileUpload']);`

- To use its components in your controller you'll have also to inject `FileUploader` so you can access its API.

`myApp.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function ($scope, FileUploader) {`

Answer (score 1):

You need following ways.

If you have FileUploader.js file

- track the files to your main html page after angular.js script before main.js(app.js)
- Then configure it by this way

  `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'fileUpload']);
              myApp.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function ($scope, fileUpload) {

              // Your code 
              }]);`

If you have any doubt, please see this discussion :- [Injecting Dependencies in config() modules - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485900/injecting-dependencies-in-config-modules-angularjs)